# Concise application of a binary function to rows of a (m x 2) matrix

Tags: r

Given the following matrix with weights in ls in the first column and heihts in the second colum:

```
> wgt.hgt.matrix
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  180   70
[2,]  156   67
[3,]  128   64
[4,]  118   66
[5,]  202   72
```

I am looking for a concise way to apply this a binary function like

```
function(lb, inch) { (lb/inch**2)*703 } -> bmi
```

to each row of the matrix, resulting in an array, list or vector of with the 5 resulting BMI values. One way I found uses the `apply` function:

```
apply(wgt.hgt.matrix, 1, function(row) bmi(row[1], row[2]))
```

But a splat operator as in Ruby (*) would help making the call more concise and clear:

```
apply(wgt.hgt.matrix, 1, function(row) bmi(*row))
```

Does an equivalent to the splat operator exist, i.e. a syntax element telling R to split all vector-like objects to populate argument lists? Are there other, simpler or more concise suggestion for the `apply` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the bmi() function as a vectorized solution is preferable since it has all vectorized operators, as was illustrated in Joshua's answer. You can also do this with:

```
colnames(wgt.hgt.matrix) <- c("lb", "inch")
with( as.data.frame(wgt.hgt.matrix), bmi(lb,inch) )
# [1] 25.82449 24.43039 21.96875 19.04362 27.39313
```

Unfortunately matrices are not good substrate for constructing environments using 'with' so coercing to a dataframe was needed above. You *could* get an `apply` solution (which will be less time-efficient than a vectorized approach)  to work with a version of bmi() re-ritten to take a vector with named elements (as created above):

```
 bmi <- function(vec) { (vec['lb']/vec['inch']**2)*703 }
 apply(wgt.hgt.matrix, 1, function(row)  bmi(row ) )
# [1] 25.82449 24.43039 21.96875 19.04362 27.39313
```

Comment: This did not specifically answer my question concerning the existence or non-existence of 'splat' in R, but it seems using functions accepting a vector seems indeed the closest possible thing in R.

Comment: I do not know of a splat-equivalent function. There are functions with the name of `.` that operate in specific contexts like `bquote` or `plyr::ddply` that either evaluate or expand their arguments in a fashion appropriate to that function. You could possibly construct something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but what's wrong with:

```
wgt.hgt.matrix <-
  structure(c(180L,156L,128L,118L,202L,70L,67L,64L,66L,72L), .Dim=c(5L,2L))
bmi <- function(lb, inch) (lb/inch**2)*703
bmi(wgt.hgt.matrix[,1], wgt.hgt.matrix[,2])
```

Update:

Based on the OP's comment, it seems like `do.call` would work more generally:

```
# put each matrix column in a separate list element
lc <- lapply(1:ncol(wgt.hgt.matrix), function(i) wgt.hgt.matrix[,i])
# call 'bmi' with one argument for each column / list element
do.call(bmi, lc)
```

Comment: In the specific problem i posed, this solution is fine. However, if I wanted to apply an 8-ary function, to an 8-colum matrix, I there would a eight repetitions of the same matrix name. Hence my questions refers to the closest equivalent to a 'splat-operator'.

Comment: @neradis: I have no idea what a 'splat-operator' is (and I'm not going to look it up to help you), so it would have been helpful if your question mentioned your need to use this with a function having 8 arguments.  See my edit for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can get pretty close to the syntax you're looking for with do.call:

```
## Setup
wgt.hgt.matrix=matrix(c(180,70,156,67,128,64,118,66,202,72),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
bmi = function(lb, inch) { (lb/inch**2)*703 }
## The action
apply(wgt.hgt.matrix, 1, function(row) do.call(bmi,as.list(row)))
```

do.call() is actually more flexible than just a splat operator, in that you can use the list names to give the argument names.